# Getting site URL from JavaScript in OrchardCore module

Tags: javascript, orchardcms

So I have a custom Orchard Core module which contains an endpoint.
Also within the module I will have JavaScript that responds to click events and needs to POST to my module endpoint.

I can invoke via POSTMAN and confirm the endpoint works, but how can my JavaScript obtain the base URL/site URL in order to add the endpoint path?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far

Comment: I'm modifying the 'Agency' theme in OrchardCore. So the html template has linked JavaScript that currently does client side validation then an ajax POST to PHP. I want to replace the URL the PHP with a dynamic link to a Custom email module.

Comment: If there was an orchard service that allowed me to get the host/tenant, I would then need to pass this value to the JavaScript file somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web page I added the link:

`<form id="myForm" name="postme" novalidate data-post-url="{{"~/MyModule/MyEndpoint" | href }}">`

In Javacript I access using:

`$.ajax({
        url: $form["0"].dataset.postUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          ...
        }`

Answer (score 1):

When working within a CMS such as orchard I usually put API endpoints in data attributes. This means you can use URL helpers to create your URLs. So for example:

```
<div id="my-config" data-post-url="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")"></div>
```

Then access this in your javascript:

```
var configElement = document.getElementById("my-config");
var postUrl = configElement.dataset.postUrl;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @GadgetGeekUK `<div id="some-id" data-apiurl="@Url.Action(...)">` and in your js: `$("#some-id").data("apiurl");`

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose this is similar to getting the values in CSHTML, then setting 'GLOBAL' JavaScript variables in the same page, and accessing those variables in the JS file. (But one step cleaner!)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
```

This should give you only the protocol and domain name, without any paths or parameters added to it.

Comment: As this is OrchardCore, there may be multi tenants.